# Emulator not shutting down

Tags: android, android-emulator

I m using windows 7 ,android SDK 2.2 API 11. My emulator does not shut down.
After giving command to shut down it takes unlimited time for processing but don't shutdown.

Comment: Best I ever managed was to directly kill the process, but that messes things all up.

Answer (score 0):

when shutdown emulator it will take too much time to process. The best way is to manually close the emulator.

Comment: I do so. but does it has any effect on the emulator